# What should I train in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My Town Hall is Level 7 and I have all the troops you can have at that level Town Hall. I can only hold 165 troops. Keep in mind that I don't have much dark elixir so I can't train too many dark troops. I want troops that get me 100% destruction most of the time and some good loot.

Comment: upgrade your army camps asap so you can reach the 200 cap instead of 165.

Comment: Do you have all Level 4 troops?(not including drags or DE troops)

Answer (score 2):

At TH7, my main group was one of the two sets:

For straight loot (farming base layout, higher trophy count that I want to reduce), I use:

- 100 archers
- 100 goblins (sometimes barbarians instead)

For 3-star rolling destruction, I generally used:

- 16-20 giants
- 2-4 wall breakers
- 1-2 healers (can substitute heal spell, but is more costly)
- 50/50% split barbs and archers

It won't be a big problem downscaling these until you reach 200 troop capacity, however I found it significant fly easier with the increased firepower.

I would suggest saving your dark eloxer for barbarian king (i ended up saving 4k then buying the rest with gems). The minions really aren't worth using, especially without a drill. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For a good hybrid attack, this is the setup I use.

-10 Giants

-1 Healer

-5-6 Wallbreakers

-20 Goblins

-50%/50% Barbarians and Archers

This layout usually gives me a good 2 or 3 stars, as it offers a wide variety of attacking options. If you want a strategy to use these troops effectively, First, use your archers to draw out any Clan Castle troops and destroy them. Choose the section of wall that gives you the most access to their defenses, and deploy at most five barbarians and then directly after one wallbreaker. This will distract the defenses so the wallbreaker can get through. Deploy your giants soon after. DON'T DEPLOY YOUR HEALER UNTIL ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY! Although it is an expendable unit, only use it as a last resort to heal your giants. Use your barbs, archers, and goblins accordingly to take out resources and remaining buildings/defenses.

Comment: Hey good strat but the only thing orgins i should give you tip in is where you are going to deploy wallbreakers you are gona deploy giant so why dont u deploy the giants then the wallbreakers tht way the giants work as distraction and they still get the same damage done and you dont waste those 5 barbs you get what im saying

Comment: I mean you are still gona use the giants and they are still gona get hurt the same amount if you use your starategy and thanks

Comment: You don't want the giants to lose too much health. That way they can destroy more defenses before dying.

Answer (score -1):

I usually train 20 giants, 3 wall breakers, 25 archers, 25 barbarians, 11 wizards. 2 heal spells and 1 rage spell.  That usually gets me 3 stars and good loot.